How can i get Siteid from Sharepoint using az cli?
I am trying to get files from Sharepoint document library . I have started my script as follows:
The document library is called "Files / Test"
tenant is called "testacme"
 az login
 ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com --query accessToken -o tsv)

 SITE_ID=$(curl -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/testacme.sharepoint.com:/sites/Files / Test" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" | jq -r '.id')

#rest of code to get files 

But i am getting an error
  Cannot convert the "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN> value of type 
 "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary

Any ideas on why this is happening and how i can fix it ?
UPDATED:
   az login
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource 
https://graph.microsoft.com --query accessToken -o tsv)

**$ACCESS_TOKEN = Invoke-Expression $ACCESS_TOKEN**

SITE_ID=$(curl -X GET 

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/testacme.sharepoint.com:/sites/Files / Test" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" | jq -r '.id')
#rest of code to get files

Try this code, but change from your on parameters:
$AuthToken = Invoke-Expression $AuthToken
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $Authtoken -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/testacme.sharepoint.com:/sites/Files"

So right now it looks like $AuthToken is a string. The string is formatted like you would expect a Hashtable to be, but I don't think it's actually a hashtable. What you can do to fix this is to use Invoke-Expression on the string, and that will convert it to an actual hashtable for you.

I have updated the question and put  in the change , it made no difference , same error ,? Any ideas ?
